# add a custom page before uninstall in nsis

Tags: nsis

I want to create a page and ask user for DB information like username, pwd, instance name during uninstallation and use same info for making some queries.
The only issue I am facing here is putting the custom page.IF I just declare the page like

UninstPage Custom un.dbPageEnter un.dbPageLeave

then it comes at the end but with disabled Next button(I can't click on next and run the queries now)
So, below are the steps I am able to do now

1. Create uninstaller
2. double click -> Click uninstall
3. Uninstallation progress bar runs
4. Custom page appears and i can fill DB info but next button is disabled

Questions:

1. Is it possible to get this custom page before I click uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages are displayed in the order they appear in your script.

```
UninstPage Custom un.dbPageEnter un.dbPageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
```

Comment: Thanks @Anders, I knew that pages are displayed in the order they are mentioned in script but i defined my 
UninstPage Custom un.dbPageEnter un.dbPageLeave
 just after the custom pages. 
Defining uninstall custom pages before 
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
worked for me. So, thanks again!!!